# how can i call method from another class in iPhone Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

i have trouble with calling method from another class this is my code

this is my method name

```
-(void)newDetails:(NSString *)name:(NSString *)gender:(NSString *)year:(double) in:(double)out:(NSString *)uid:(NSString *)pass:(NSString *)dob:(double) table:(double)table1{
```

i import my class and create object like this

```
#import "Personal.h"
@class Personal; 


Personal *personDetails;
```

calling that mathod like this

```
[personDetails newDetails:username:categoryMale:financeYear:0:0:userID:password:dob:0:0];
```

calling that mathod like this 
but its not working .
guide me how can call this method

Comment: Did you allocated memory to your class called?

Comment: as there are no specific details, lets start with the basic questions: have you allocated your variable before calling newDetails: method?

Comment: @KingofBliss yes i tried but its not print any thing. but i create one uiview and connected to that class to view controller.that time its working fine.why this one is happen like this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a class A that calls function in class Personal.

In `Class A.m` do `#import "Personal.h"`

Make sure that the function is defined in the `Personal.h` file otherwise it will give warning.

Now In class A when you want to call that function.
you can do.

`Personal *per=[Personal alloc]init];`

`[per newDetails:username:categoryMale:financeYear:0:0:userID:password:dob:0:0];`.

Note: If you are coming from Class Personal to Class A and then you want to call a function in Class Personal then no need to create any objects you can simply use delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the object

```
personDetails=[[Personal alloc] init] ;
```

Or if you have any Custom Initializer you can use that.